# How to import my dataset(SQL,Excel) to Parse Server?

Tags: android, parse-platform, import, parse-server, data-import

I'm trying to build an app and I need to know how to import my dataset(SQL,Excel) to Parse Server ? There are over 150 thousand data in my dataset so it would be terrible to add one by one.